# SQL Server Error while creating User

Tags: sql-server, permissions, connectivity, logins

I tried creating a user with all privileges but I am getting this error:

> #### Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Create failed for User 'Hru'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> **Additional information:**
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> 'Hru' is not a valid login or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15007)

Can anybody help me solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The error message is stating that SQL Server cannot locate a login named `Hiru`, or you do not have the privilege required to create a user.

The SQL Server security model consists<sup>1</sup> of a *server-level* login that provides access at the server level.  Logins are then associated to a *user* inside each database.  The user typically has the same name as the login, although that is not required.

[Creating a login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver) and [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver) is easy to do with T-SQL, as in:

```
USE master;
CREATE LOGIN [Hiru] WITH PASSWORD = 'pwd';
USE mydb;
CREATE USER [Hiru] FOR LOGIN [Hiru];
```

Using a T-SQL script provides more direct control over the process, and allows better troubleshooting.

---

<sup>1 - unless you're using the [contained database security model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

First create a global login under Security -> Logins

Then add the user in Databases -> Database -> Security -> Users